# How to combine buckets using vectors

Tags: c++

I'm working an a project for school and I'm having troubles combining buckets.

This is my method I have now.

```
void combineBuckets() {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numBuckets; ++i) {
    auto bucket = globalBuckets->getBucket(i);
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < globalBuckets->getNumItemsInABucket(i); ++j) {
      list[j] = bucket[i];
    }
  }
}
```

`globalBuckets` is a global object for the class I am working with.
`getBucket()` returns the bucket
`getNumBuckets()` returns the number of items in that bucket.

The main problem I'm having is with the inner loop.
the instructions say:

> - Loop through the amount of buckets
> - Get the individual bucket out of the `globalBuckets`
> - Copy all Items from that individual bucket into the list array.

These are the variables:

```
unique_ptr<unsigned long[]> list;
unique_ptr<ManyBuckets> globalBuckets;
vector< vector<unsigned long> > arr;
```

`arr` is a private method inside the a `ManyBuckets` class.

This program is supposed to take `n` amount of buckets and combine them into the list array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bucket[i]` should be `bucket[j]` and `list`, assuming it points to an array large enough to hold all the buckets, should use an index that increments for every insertion. So change it to:

```c++
void combineBuckets() {
  int idx = 0;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numBuckets; ++i) {
    auto bucket = globalBuckets->getBucket(i);
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < globalBuckets->getNumItemsInABucket(i); ++j) {
      list[idx++] = bucket[j];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver! That worked! I can go to bed now :) Thanks!